# How could double validation be added in marshmallow "fields"?(PeeWee)

Tags: regex, flask, peewee, marshmallow, flask-peewee

I send requests to a RESTful API. Also I have a PeeWee model to keep the responses. I check the validations with Marshmallow.

In the response body, there is a variable that is not certain data type(Integer or String). I want my PeeWee model have multiple validation.

Here is the example:

```
class Example(Schema):
    availableLimit = fields.Str(
        required=False, allow_none=True, validate=validate.Regexp(REGEX.NUMBER_LARGE)
    )
```

In the API response, `availableLimit` have exactly 2 possibilities:  the string "UNLIMITED" or any Integer.
How can I validate it with the Marshmallow fields validation like `validate=validate.Regexp(REGEX.NUMBER_LARGE && REGEX.UNLIMITED_STRING)`?

Additionally `REGEX.NUMBER_LARGE` and `REGEX.UNLIMITED_STRING` are my patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can import `post_dump` from `marshmallow`. You can then use `post_dump` as a decorator method in your schema class.

eg

```
from marshmallow import ValidationError, post_dump
class Example(Schema):
    availableLimit = fields.Str(required=False, allow_none=True,validate=validate.Regexp(REGEX.NUMBER_LARGE))
    @post_dump('availableLimit')
    def multiple_validation(self, value):
        ....
```

I hope this is clear